# the target "UpdateDesignTimeXaml" does not exit in the project error in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am new to mobile application developing. When I was creating a new `.xaml` file in new solution in the `Xamarin Studio`.

It gave the error:

> "the target "UpdateDesignTimeXaml" does not exit".

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you update Xamarin.Forms package recently after creating the project ? Or is an update available for it now (If available it will be mentioned right next to the name of package within Packages folder in Solution explorer) ?

Answer (score 9):

Build errors can occur if you have updated the Xamarin.Forms nuget to a newer version that requires `UpdateDesignTimeXaml`.

- Close and reopen `Xamarin Studio`.
- Clean all and ReBuild your project.

Ref: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49152/problem-initializecomponent-and-pcl

> A workaround for this is to remove the MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml from the Custom Tool of the xaml file properties in VS. Save, add MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml again and save again will force MSBuild to recreate the *g.cs file.

Comment: This worked, I cleaned and closed VisualStudio --> and rebuild it .. "
"Closing the VisualStudio" is the Key.

Answer (score 4):

I had this with Visual Studio for Mac. 
I fixed it by:

1. closing VS
2. manually deleting the packages, bin and obj folders
3. restart the project in VS
4. restore NuGet packages, build and run.

Answer (score 2):

Got same issue in Visual Studio for Mac. Worked find with

closing VS
manually deleting the packages, bin and obj folders in both android folder and main folder
restart the project in VS
restore NuGet packages, build and run.